# How to train custom speech model in Microsoft cognitive services Speech to text

Tags: text, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I'm doing a POC with Speech to text. **I need to recognize specific words like "D-STUM"** (daily stand up meeting). The problem is, every time I tell my program to recognize "D-STUM", i get "Destiny", "This theme", etc.

I already went on speech.microsoft.com/.../customspeech, and **I've recorded around 40 wav files of people saying "D-STUM"**. I've also created a file named "trans.txt" which contains every wav file with the word "D-STUM" after each file. Like this : 
D_stum_1.wav    D-STUM
D_stum_2.wav    D-STUM
D_stum_3.wav    D-STUM
D_stum_4.wav    D-STUM
...

Then I uploaded a zip containing the wav files and the trans.txt file, train a model with those datas, and created an endpoint. I referenced this endpoint on my soft, and launched it.

I expect my custom speech-to-text to recognize people saying "D-STUM" and displaying "D-STUM" as text. I never had "D-STUM" displayed after customizing the model.

Did I do something wrong? Is it the right way to do a custom training? 
Is 40 samples not enough for the model to be properly trained?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Speech has several ways to get a better understanding of specific words:

- By providing audio sample with their transcription, as you have done
- By providing text sample (without audio)

Based on my previous use-cases, I would highly suggest to create a training file with 5 to 10 sentences in it, each one containing "D-STUM" in its usage context. Then duplicate those sentences like 10 to 20 times in the file.

It worked for us to understand specific words.

Additionally, if you are using "en-US" or "de-DE" as target language, you can use a pronunciation file, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-test-data?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#guidelines-to-create-a-pronunciation-file)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight!

can you specify what you meant when you said "create a training file with 5 or 10 sentences in it"? Like i Create 5-10 wav file with 1 sentence containing "D-STUM" in it, and a trans.txt file with 5-10 lines containing wav files and sentences transcription?

Comment: You're welcome. In any case, you have to test and try to tweak it in order to work... Depending on the terms, text training may be enough, but not every time. Another advice: start with a word without "-" in it, it may be another source of problems!

Comment: No no, there is no audio implicated in what I'm talking about, it's only 1 text file with sentences in it.

Comment: Ah, ok I get it. It will understand D-stum by the sentence around it. I'll definitely give it a try. Thanks again!